# Change fontFamily of TextInput in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native

Guys I have a problem that occured to me. Im working currently on an app and I implemented some custom fonts, they work everywhere in my app beside my textInput I created.

```
<TextInput
   multiline={true}
   numberOfLines={40}
   onChangeText={(text) => setTextMessage(text)}
   value={textMessage}
   style={{fontFamily:chosenTextFam, fontSize: 14, textAlign: 'center'}}
/>
```

"chosenTextFam" is a hook I have saved just like that and presetted to one font:

```
const [chosenTextFam, setChosenTextFam] = useState("AmaticBold");
```

Also I change dynamicly the font when I press some buttons. Here you can see it:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setChosenTextFam("AmaticBold")}>
   <Feather name="pen-tool" size={30} color="white" />
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setChosenTextFam('Magnus')}>
   <Feather name="pen-tool" size={30} color="blue" />
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setChosenTextFam('Otto')}>
   <Feather name="pen-tool" size={30} color="orange" />
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setChosenTextFam('Gwibble')}>
   <Feather name="pen-tool" size={30} color="green" />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

When I change the font clicking on the buttons nothing happens. I can type whatever I want in the Input, but the font in TextInput stays default. Can anybody help me with this problem?

EDIT:

I also get two errors if I want to type in something into the textinput. They dont crash the app but still pop up.
1.

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `object`
> supplied to `ComponentWrapper`, expected `string`.

2. 

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `object`
> supplied to `ForwardRef(TextInput)`, expected `string`.

Both are refering to my TextInput component, I just dont understand the errors.

Comment: Did you link the fonts to be imported in your android/ios project? Otherwise it will only work if the devices you are running the app on has installated the selected font

Comment: @gdalduzzi Yes that exactly what I want. Like I said, the fonts are working everywhere beside the textinput in my app.

Also Im wondering because one month ago when I coded this part it worked perfectly, and now since I came back to working on the app its not working anymore.. there must be a way to make this work again

Comment: Have you added .ttf file under correct dir and recompiled?

Comment: @Rohit 100% yes, because I checked it but also because the fonts are working in all other parts of the app. Wrong dir cant be the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some days of research I found a solution to this problem in a forum related to react native. Here is the crucial part of the code, fixed.

```
<TextInput
   multiline={true}
   numberOfLines={40}
   onChangeText={(text) => setTextMessage({text})}
   value={textMessage}
   style={{fontWeight: 'normal', fontFamily:chosenTextFam, fontSize: 14, 
   textAlign:"center", width:"90%", height:"80%", 
   marginTop:60}}
/>
```

The essential part you need to add to solve the bug is only **fontWeight: 'normal'** to the style props because else the custom font will not be applied to the TextInput.